# Chrome is behaving strange bootstrap modal

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, web-applications

We are experiencing an strange issue. On Chrome browser when we show Modal pop up, we are getting a black background flicking and this is not happening on other browsers. We have also using Chrome Dev Tools but we found nothing that causing this.

[image: Chrome]

Comment: I'm having a similar issue...

Comment: when did it started happening to you @MaxwellS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Chrome Settings turn off

> Use Hardware acceleration when enable

and relaunch Chrome